# Why is my JavaScript code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I keep getting the "Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier" JS error with this code:

```
function hashStuff() {
    var messageID = window.location.hash.replace('#inbox-', '');
    var msgSubject = $('#subject_' + messageID).html();
    setTimeout("readMessage2(" + messageID + ", " + msgSubject + ");", 300);
}
if (window.location.hash) {
    setTimeout("hashStuff();", 400);
}
```

I've also tried:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    function hashStuff() {
    var messageID = window.location.hash.replace('#inbox-', '');
    var msgSubject = $('#subject_' + messageID).html();
    setTimeout("readMessage2(" + messageID + ", " + msgSubject + ");", 300);
}
    setTimeout("hashStuff();", 400);
}
```

Neither of them work.

What I was trying to do was get information from the elements but I guess the page wasn't loaded yet so I need it to trigger after a second. I put it in a function so I can use a timeout and it will not work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what line is causing the error?

Comment: avoid using timers, very inconsistent, just use the jQuery `ready`

Comment: To the person who downvoted: thanks for commenting about why you downvoted! :|

Comment: Your title kind of sucks.  You are creating a string to eval using setTimeout - I bet those parameters need quotes.

Comment: @James Yeah, I found that out now. What should the title be then?

Comment: @Nathan well you could maybe figure out the line of code with the syntax error, take a guess at the part of the line that's causing it, and make up a title like "Why does 'foo..bar' cause a syntax error?" Even if "foo..bar" isn't the cause, it's still more specific that, essentially, "Halp!!".

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, well it's all fixed now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the script inside `$(document).ready(function() {//script here});` . That will make sure that it is run after all the elements have loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: But another problem is that it keeps repeating. So it keeps repeatedly calling the `readMessage2()` function now with `document.ready` over and over and over again. What part was I supposed to put in the .ready, the whole if() or just a part of it?

Comment: @Nathan You were supposed to put the code you wanted to run in the first place (get `messageID` and `msgSubject` and call `readMessage2()` I guess). No need for setTimeout() if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 4):

If your messageID is something like 1234 and the msgSubject is Hello World, then the statement being evaluated is:

```
readMessage2(1234, Hello World);
```

Which, clearly, is incorrect and error-inducing.

The correct code is:

```
setTimeout( function() {readMessage2(messageID,msgSubject);}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your code inside `ready` block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your code
});
```